# EXCEL: drag-across of INDIRECT function does not change cell reference between " " marks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I'm having an issue with dragging cell formulas across and having them update the column reference.

I have multiple formula referencing a single cell (cell A2) to get a numeric value to incorporate into a cell reference - so I can update this single cell and have all the formula calculate over increasing ranges as I add data to my spreadsheet each month.  I have used the INDIRECT function over several formula in the same column, but when I drag across to the right, the column letter reference does not update because it is in " " marks.

I did find a similar solution on the forum, but am confused since my " " marks contain two column/letter references.

The formula I am trying to drag across are like this:

```
=ConsecUpDays(INDIRECT("D25:D" &$A$2))
=MaxPosSequence(INDIRECT("D25:D" &$A$2))
=AVERAGE(IF((INDIRECT("D25:D" &$A$2))>0,((INDIRECT("D25:D" &$A$2))),""))
=COUNTIF((INDIRECT("D25:D" &$A$2)),"<>0")
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use the INDEX equivalent and discard INDIRECT.

```
'locked as string with INDIRECT
=ConsecUpDays(INDIRECT("D25:D" &$A$2))
'relative column D with INDEX
=ConsecUpDays(INDEX(D:D, 25):INDEX(D:D, $A$2))
```

Additionally, INDEX is non-volatile so you should not get quite as much calculation lag.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for that solution - looks more straightforward than what I came up with!

### I'm posting what I did do in the end to solve this:

Very big Thank You _kev and John Topley.

I see what you meant now _kev. Thanks John, I was able to use that to amend my formula and make them draggable.

My formula now read:

```
 =ConsecUpDays(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(25,COLUMN(D:D))&":"&ADDRESS($A$2,COLUMN(D:D))))
=MaxPosSequence(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(25,COLUMN(D:D))&":"&ADDRESS($A$2,COLUMN(D:D))))
```

=AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(25,COLUMN(D:D))&":"&ADDRESS($A$2,COLUMN(D:D))),">0",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(25,COLUMN(D:D))&":"&ADDRESS($A$2,COLUMN(D:D))))

```
=COUNTIF((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(25,COLUMN(D:D))&":"&ADDRESS($A$2,COLUMN(D:D)))),"<>0")
```

Much appreciated.